# Wildcard folder on website?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder named "keyword" for my website, such as this:  http://www.mysite.com/keyword/

In the folder I only have an index.php file.  Regardless of what someone types in after the folder, I need the index.php to show.  For example, http://www.mysite.com/keyword/this-is-a-test should show the index.php file's content but without changing the URL.

Everything I've tried seems to fail - I'm working with the .htaccess in my /keyword/ folder.  Regardless of what I put there I seem to keep getting a 404 error.  Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure it's something small and simple that I just don't know how to do.

Comment: Why do you keep your attempts secret? No way for us to tell yo what your problem might be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule - index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this can fix your problem (.htaccess in your root)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/keyword/(.*)$ /keyword/index.php?keyword=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}   [L]
```